# wordpress htaccess issue

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i have been writing `.htaccess` for the site `http://hoteldevserver.com/~hamislan`/ when i can the permalink to `/%postname%/` its shows the following error when try to view the page.

> The requested URL `/~hamislan/info/services-amenities/` was not found on
>   this server. Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

i have my `.htaccess` file as

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

i have my wordpress file directly in `www`

Answer (score 0):

Tthis could be one of a few things.

First check that your htaccess is readable by apache. I'm assuming it is.

Then check that you have mod-rewrite enabled in apache.

Lastly, it could be this symlink issue. And to fix this, you can add this to the top of your htaccess file or your can enable it in your vhost directive (I'm just assuming you're using a vhost) Sorry I don't have an example of how to do it in the vhost off the top of my head.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
```

Also each time set your permalinks to the default and then switch it to the permalink style you want.

**EDIT**

Additionally, the url location of your website is not at the base http://hoteldevserver.com/~hamislan/

So you may need to edit your rewrite rule for base url. It's call `RewriteBase`

Right now `RewriteBase` is `/` you may need to change that to `/~hamislan/`

Comment: its showing the same error altho i add Options +FollowSymlinks to the htaccess file :(.

Comment: Yes, I edited my post. I noticed your wordpress ur is not located at the base url, so you need to edit the rewrite rule to accommodate for the fact that is at /~hasislan/ instead of /

Comment: thank you its worked actually i found that  my websever takes htaccess.txt as the .htaccess file